# Select postion image won't show on ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, appcompatactivity

I have 1 int and 1 string from intent extras with positions I want to be set image view drawable Exact image from the position from the selected item. codes work and Log show correct position but image view won't show anything in device
any ids?

// this is intent from the list item

```
Intent inspol = new Intent(getActivity(),Item_Click_open.class);
                inspol.putExtra("IMAGE_SELECT",datassss[position]);
                if (boxcolor1 == 0||boxcolor2 == 0) {
                    inspol.putExtra("IMAGE_TYPE",1);
                }
                if (boxcolor1 == 1||boxcolor2 == 1) {
                    inspol.putExtra("IMAGE_TYPE",2);
                }
                if (boxcolor1 == 2||boxcolor2 == 2) {
                    inspol.putExtra("IMAGE_TYPE",3);
                }





                        new Pair<View, String>(view.findViewById(R.id.big_image),
                                Item_Click_open.VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE),
                        new Pair<View, String>(view.findViewById(R.id.big_image),
                                Item_Click_open.VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE2));;
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(),inspol,activityOptions.toBundle());
            }
        });
```

// the activity must image view set drawable

```
Intent ilm = getIntent();
    sps = ilm.getStringExtra("IMAGE_SELECT");
    popint = ilm.getIntExtra("IMAGE_TYPE",0);


imsec = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imseccc);

if (popint == 1) {
        if (sps == "Beginner") {
            imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tree_bign));
        }
        if (sps == "Elementary") {
            imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tree_ele2));
        }
        if (sps == "Intermediate") {
            imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tree_inter));
        }
        if (sps == "Advance") {
            imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tree_advice));
        }
    }
    if (popint == 2) {
        if (sps == "Beginner") {
            imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_chery));

        }
        if (sps == "Elementary") {
            imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_limon));
        }
        if (sps == "Intermediate") {
            imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sbr));
        }
        if (sps == "Advance") {
            imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_oldfood));
        }
    }
```

Thanks for Helping!

Comment: You should use `.equals` instead of `==` when comparing strings. Like `sps.equals( "Beginner")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java's `equals` method in order to compare Strings:

```
if (sps.equals("Beginner") {
    imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tree_bign));
}
if (sps.equals("Elementary")) {
    imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tree_ele2));
}
if (sps.equals("Intermediate")) {
    imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tree_inter));
}
if (sps.equals("Advance")) {
    imsec.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tree_advice));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final String sps = ilm.getStringExtra("IMAGE_SELECT");
int popint = ilm.getIntExtra("IMAGE_TYPE", 0);

if (popint == 1) {
        switch (sps.toLowerCase()){
            case "beginner":
                imsec.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Item_Click_open.this, R.drawable.ic_tree_bign));
                break;
            case "elementary":
                imsec.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Item_Click_open.this, R.drawable.ic_tree_ele2));
                break;
            case "intermediate":
                imsec.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Item_Click_open.this, R.drawable.ic_tree_inter));
                break;
            case "advance":
                imsec.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Item_Click_open.this, R.drawable.ic_tree_advice));
                break;

        }
    } else if (popint == 2){
        switch (sps.toLowerCase()){
            case "beginner":
                imsec.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Item_Click_open.this, R.drawable.ic_chery));
                break;
            case "elementary":
                imsec.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Item_Click_open.this, R.drawable.ic_limon));
                break;
            case "intermediate":
                imsec.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Item_Click_open.this, R.drawable.ic_sbr));
                break;
            case "advance":
                imsec.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Item_Click_open.this, R.drawable.ic_oldfood));
                break;

        }
    }
```